# speed up visual studio 2010 build asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build

Right now our team's ASP.NET MVC 2.0 web project takes about 4 minutes to do build on debug. We have the following things included on our project:

- t4MVC templates
- compiling the asp.net mvc's views on all builds

My work pc is a

- Intel core 2 duo T7250 @ 2.00 Mhz.
- Windows 7 32 bit ultimate
- 4 gb ram

I am also getting the same build times, on my desktop

- Intel core 2 Duo E6550 Conroe 2.33GHz
- 6gb ram
- ocz ssd drive

I do not see any difference between my desktop and laptop? I am guessing that it CPU bound? I may need to upgrade my box?

I did set this to false, and the build times went from 3 minutes before now down to 5 seconds.

```
 <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

I believe the problem is the compiling the asp.net mvc views. I am still need to see why it takes so long?

Comment: You really haven't provided any information about what you're building (e.g. number of files, etc.).  Also, run PERFMON.EXE and watch your CPU and RAM and see what's the bottleneck.

Comment: CPU bound sounds unlikely. Try putting the whole shebang (including the BCL) on a RAM drive. :)

Comment: "My work pc is a Intel core 2 duo T7250 @ 2.00 Mhz." It's only running at 0.002GHz, that's why! :-)

Comment: Hah, Hah, use a calculator(mhz) as my desktop machine!!!

Comment: @user154366 "I did set this to false, and the build times are from 3 minutes to 5 seconds" - what does this mean? That building the views takes 2 minutes and 55 seconds?

Comment: hey, I just updated the main thread. I mean that the build was taking 3-4 minutes with <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews> and now takes 5 seconds with <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>.

Comment: @user154366 Well, how many views and partials do you have? Are they unusually complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried all of the options given too me. I upgrade my machine @ home and can build under 15 seconds with true. I am guessing that it is a CPU bound problem.

Comment: I was able to overclock my machine using asus software from 2.8 to 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried building the project with msbuild instead of from visual studio?  this may give you a clue where the bottlenecks are.

See also:

- [How to troubleshoot long builds in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659911/how-to-troubleshoot-long-builds-in-visual-studio)
- [Very long build time in Visual Studio.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638775/very-long-build-time-in-visual-studio)